# mdadm: /dev/md/3 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array

Tags: network-attached-storage

Having two RAID discs from WD NAS and would like to recover data using Ubuntun Linux.

Disc information as below:

```
{DISC 1}
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HDS5C4040AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DE14E57B-3139-4F22-BB20-4EC310426156

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1  1032192    5031935    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  5031936    9031679    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3    30720    1032191    1001472  489M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  9031680 7814035455 7805003776  3.6T Linux RAID

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


{DISC 2}
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: K392            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5781EC68-9563-44B4-BBF2-D205379F1082

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1  1032192    5031935    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd2  5031936    9031679    3999744  1.9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd3    30720    1032191    1001472  489M Linux RAID
/dev/sdd4  9031680 7814035455 7805003776  3.6T Linux RAID

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

---

{RUN}

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
```

ERROR CODE:

```
...
mdadm: /dev/sdd3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/2, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/2, slot 1.
mdadm: added /dev/sdb3 to /dev/md/2 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdd3 to /dev/md/2 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md/2 has been started with 2 drives.
...
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/3
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/md/2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got e5e5e5e5)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/2
...
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd4
...
mdadm: /dev/sdd3 has wrong uuid.
...
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 has wrong uuid.
.
.
.
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 is identified as a member of /dev/md/3, slot 1.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md/3
mdadm: added /dev/sdb4 to /dev/md/3 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md/3 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/3
Segmentation fault
```

---

Any suggestion what I could do to recover the data?

Comment: What RAID level is used?

Comment: RAID 0, assuming. As one of the HDD says it's LINEAR.   Both drives were moved out from WD NAS, and the setting should be the default.

Comment: RAID 0 is striping, so the data is only present on one drive or the other.  If the array was created using two (or more) drives and you now only have one, it is unrecoverable.  What other partitions *were* in `/dev/md/3` and where are they now?